# sed/awk delete equals if NOT followed by 3D

Tags: regex, sed, awk, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to remove the equals sign 
only if is **not** followed by 3D. Here there is an example.

```
NB2HI4B2F4XWM3LNFZCGK3DJOZSXE6L=PNZSS4Y3PFZZWGSZB5GUTGKPLE=ONZXA33PNZSXEQ
```

So this should became

```
NB2HI4B2F4XWM3LNFZCGK3DJOZSXE6LPNZSS4Y3PFZZWGSZB5GUTGKPLEONZXA33PNZSXEQ
```

If is possible could I have the solution in `awk` and `sed`? I know that here is plenty of explanation about how to do it, but the regex aren't so easy at the begin.

Comment: If your input is quoted printable, the proper solution is to use a quoted-printable decoder. This looks like you had previously an escaped newline and you forgot to remove the `=` before the newline which escapes it in QP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately neither `sed` nor `awk` support [look-arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and you really want to use negative look-ahead here to match all `=` not followed by 3D `(?!3D)`. Both `python` and `perl` support look-arounds.

One way with `python`:

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub('=(?!3D)','','=3D=3=1=D3D====3D')
=3D31D3D=3D
```

One way with `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/=(?!3D)//g' <<< "=3D=3=1=D3D====3D" 
=3D31D3D=3D
```

Comment: seems working thanks ;)
another thing If I'd delete equals if is not followed by 3D **and** another equals?

Comment: @marcodv Just add the extra `=` in the look-ahead so `=(?!3D=)` would only match an `=` not followed by `3D=`.

Answer (score 0):

dirty and quick awk one-liner:

```
awk '{gsub(/=3D/,"\x99");gsub(/=/,"");gsub(/\x99/,"=3D")}1' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "====xxx==yy=3D=3Dyy==zz=3D="|awk '{gsub(/=3D/,"\x99");gsub(/=/,"");gsub(/\x99/,"=3D")}1'     
xxxyy=3D=3Dyyzz=3D
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
awk 'NR>1 && /^3D/{print RS}1' RS=\\= ORS= file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/=3D/\n/g;s/=//g;s/\n/=3D/g' file
```